# Is there an undo column feature in Word?

Tags: ms-office

I am new to Microsoft Word.  I accidentally formatted a section as columns and now cannot undo it.  My whole (large!) document is now in column mode and I cannot get it back to normal mode.

I have tried View/Styles/clear formatting and it only clears all my other formatting but not the columns.

Comment: I suppose  you are speaking about "Microsoft" Word. There's (to my knowledge) no such thing as "Macbook Word". Please edit your question and clarify. Then: what do you mean by "column" mode? Did you format your document as having more columns? What happens if you reduce the number of columns to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- you are speaking about Microsoft Word
- you formatted your document with multiple columns
- you are using Word 2011 (latest version)

You can change the column setting in the "Format", "Columns..." menu

[image]